# Seeking a clue about an Android app crash related to MediaCodec

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I am sorry but I do not even know how to name this crash in the topic. The app uses MediaCodec to stream H.264 video. The following is the crash report.  Any clue to help prevent such crash will be greatly appreciated.

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:4.4.4/KTU84P/1227136:user/release-keys'
Revision: '11'
pid: 16129, tid: 16236, name: MediaCodec_loop >>> net.mydomain.myapp <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
r0 00000000 r1 00003f6c r2 00000006 r3 00000000
r4 00000006 r5 00000000 r6 00003f6c r7 0000010c
r8 400cc559 r9 4e4d6000 sl 4bb4c75c fp 400922ec
ip 40b00024 sp 4e5d3838 lr 40058fe5 pc 40067f90 cpsr 000f0010
d0 2036203a64656c76 d1 61662029474e4973
d2 656761747362692e d3 4d2f746867697220
d4 65646f4361696465 d5 38383a7070632e63
d6 5f4b434548432037 d7 6174536d20285145
d8 0000000000000000 d9 0000000000000000
d10 0000000000000000 d11 3f80000000000000
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 41495fa84b63e4a8 d17 654d2f616964656d
d18 0000000000000000 d19 0000000000000000
d20 0000000000000000 d21 0002000200020002
d22 0010001000100010 d23 0000000000000000
d24 0002aaa80002aaa8 d25 0002aaa80002aaa8
d26 0707070703030303 d27 000000400000003f
d28 0001000000010000 d29 0001000000010000
d30 00f7400000f48000 d31 00fc800000f9c000
scr 20000012

backtrace:
#00 pc 00021f90 /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01 pc 00012fe1 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
#02 pc 000131f5 /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
#03 pc 00011f2b /system/lib/libc.so
#04 pc 00021844 /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
#05 pc 0000690b /system/lib/libcutils.so (__android_log_assert+86)
#06 pc 0006d775 /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::MediaCodec::onMessageReceived(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+404)
#07 pc 00009435 /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::ALooperRoster::deliverMessage(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+152)
#08 pc 00008f0f /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::ALooper::loop()+198)
#09 pc 0000e9ed /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+104)
#10 pc 0000e58f /system/lib/libutils.so
#11 pc 0000d170 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#12 pc 0000d308 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)

code around pc:
40067f70 e8bd00f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000 
40067f80 ea006d81 e92d50f0 e3a07f43 ef000000 
40067f90 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000 
40067fa0 ea006d79 e92d50f0 e3a070ee ef000000 
40067fb0 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000 
40067fc0 ea006d71 f200429a bf008069 f040f891 
40067fd0 4001e92d d3412a10 0300f1c0 030ff013 
40067fe0 eba2d01d ea5f0203 bf447cc3 eb01f811 
40067ff0 eb01f800 f811bf21 f811cb01 f800eb01 
40068000 f800cb01 ea5feb01 da037c43 030df9a1 
40068010 031df980 f921d303 f900070d 3a40071d 
40068020 f921d30b f921020d f891420d 3a40f100 
40068030 022df900 422df900 3220d2f3 f921d305 
40068040 f1a2020d f9000220 f102022d f0120220 
40068050 d0030f10 0a0df921 0a2df900 7c42ea5f 
40068060 f921d303 f900070d da03070d 030df9a1 

code around lr:
40058fc4 447b4b13 42b3e010 6a1ed10e 44784811 
40058fd4 ec84f7fb ea0ef00d 46224631 efd0f00e 
40058fe4 d00a3001 e00b2400 2b00681b 480ad1eb 
40058ff4 44782403 ec72f7fb f001e002 6804fa23 
40059004 fa20f001 46206005 bf00bd70 0003b3de 
40059014 0003b3d2 0003b3ca 0003b3a6 bf7ef7ff 
40059024 4a3e4b3d e92d447b b08b43f0 4606589c 
40059034 6823460d 930946a1 fa04f001 8000f8d0 
40059044 d0482d00 f00f4628 280fff9b d8444604 
40059054 ffe4f7ff d1064286 4629200f e8d8f00d 
40059064 d03c2800 482ee02e f7fb4478 482debb6 
40059074 e0154478 d11342b0 482b6a06 f7fb4478 
40059084 4a2aec2e 46332120 a801447a f83af013 
40059094 a8012101 fb54f01a 46061c42 e011d104 
400590a4 28006800 e02cd1e6 46294630 f00d4622 
400590b4 1c43e914 d11e4607 f9c4f001 29046801
```

**Edited on 2014-09-05:**
I have just examined every native crash like this.  All of them are from Android 4.4 Devices.

Comment: That's an assertion failure.  Look in the log above the crash report to find the message from the `assert` itself.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. This report was copied from Google Play Developer Console. Do I have the luxury to check the log?  If not, is there a way to capture the information without incurring too much negative impact on the app's performance?

Comment: Hmm.  Do you see a log snapshot anywhere in the output, or is what you posted the entirety of it?  (Recent devices include a bit of the logs in the tombstones, but I don't know what gets posted to the console.)

Comment: Yes, I posted everything.  I have just double-checked it.  There are a few crashes like this.  This one is from Nexus 5 (hammerhead).

Comment: @fadden I have just examined every native crash like this.  All of them are from Android 4.4 Devices.

Comment: Well, the assert is firing in `MediaCodec::onMessageReceived()`, which is in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/kitkat-release/media/libstagefright/MediaCodec.cpp .  See all those `CHECK` macros?  One of them is failing.  This is a bug in the platform.  A workaround may be possible, but it's hard to know what without knowing which assertion is failing.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent crashing the app without having to find and fix the bug temporarily?  It is OK, though not ideal, if MediaCodec stops decoding H.264 if it is not happy with something.